# How to enable Maintenance mode in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I'll do some database upgrade. I wanted to show a maintenance page to all the user who visit my app when upgrade is going on. 
I wanted to show Maintenance message in all routes.

Is there a hook to redirect all request to Maintenance page template in spring boot avoiding all the controllers? So that no matter where my user go they will see this Maintenance page.

I couldn't find any resource. Any clue will be much appreciated.

Comment: May be just put nginx (or another proxy server) in front of your app and create maintenance page on it

Comment: isn't there any other way to stop all controller and show maintenance template from app itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem that can be solved by a javax.servlet.Filter. You can intercept all requests to *.html and forward or redirect to “maintenance.html”

Comment: I get it, thanks. So what is the right way to do Maintenance activity? Another server proxy with maintenance template or same server with redirect all request to maintenance template approach ?

Comment: I answered the original question with the assumption that the Spring Boot application is doing the database maintenance and there's a dynamic flag that temporarily disables the  normal endpoints.

Comment: There's no correct approach. It completely depends on the technology around your Spring Boot application and how it is deployed. You can stop the application, create temporary rules (in apache or ingress or ELB) or you can handle the requests in the app.